# Are there any Windows 7 applications that can veiw RAID status on a PERC 6/e?

Tags: windows-7, hardware-raid, perc6, dell-openmanage

I am trying to troubleshoot an MD1000 that is plugged into a PERC 6/e that is in a Precision T3600 running Windows 7. Windows can see, use, and push and pull data on the RAID 50 array on the MD1000, I just can't see the status of the controller or the status of the RAID or any kind of management information I need to be able to say the problem is fixed from inside Windows. I can reboot into the PERC BIOS with no problems, though.

Everything that I have read, you need OMSA, which doesn't install the administration part on Windows 7 and/or Precision line computers, just the web client. Which isn't useful in the least. There doesn't seem to be a Dell specific Windows application to view this information (again, except for OMSA), so if there is a 3rd party application, that would be useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those PERC controllers are actually manufactured by LSI. You can manage them using LSI's MegaCLI command-line utility, though it may take a bit of reading up before you will be comfortable with using the tool.

I would recommend just searching around for an appropriate exe, and a CLI manual. If you're moderately familiar with the hardware, you should be able to figure out some of the basic actions on your own.